# Does jQuery guarantee its compatibility with extending prototype of Array or Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, prototype

I want to extend Array and Object like the following code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    Array.prototype.x = 3
    Object.prototype.y = 4

    var a = [1, 2]
    for (var i in a) {
        alert(i + ': ' + a[i])
    }
})

/*
[result]
0: 1
1: 2
x: 3
y: 4
*/
```

Will this code cause any trouble to jQuery operation in current version or future version of jQuery?

Comment: If you are expecting the properties to be returned in a particular order, you may be disappointed by some widely used browsers.

Comment: Also, jQuery does unprotected for..in iteration in many places so extending Object.prototype **will** cause issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `Array.prototype`, I think you're pretty safe. I don't think there's an explicit guarantee anywhere, but jQuery has been co-existing on sites with Prototype and MooTools for years, and they both extend the `Array.prototype`. I don't think the jQuery team would want to break compatibility with those libraries.

But: **Never extend the `Object.prototype`**. That may well break jQuery's own code and will almost certainly break plug-in code as well. Most `for..in` loops assume that `{}` will have no enumerable properties. If you add to `Object.prototype`, you're making that assumption invalid. (Unless you use the new ECMAScript5 `defineProperty` feature that lets you make properties non-enumerable, but it's not widely-supported yet. For fun, though, [you can try it out here](http://jsbin.com/abice4/2).)

Comment: thank you very much. your answer is very helpful. 
ill use `defineProperty` for my software and extend both `Array` and `Object` with `defineProperty` without anxiety.
(i dont care some browsers dont support `defineProperty`)

Comment: @js_: Glad that helped! Hate to tell you, it's not *some* browsers that don't (yet) support it, it's the browsers currently used by the *overwhelming* majority of people -- see [these stats](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2) and [these](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201003-201103). Firefox didn't support it until FF4, IE didn't support it (for your use case) until IE9 (IE8 had very limited support for it related to DOM nodes)... So before too long, Firefox users will have it (they update early), but IE users... *sigh* ;-)

Comment: thanks for your comment.
im very sad to hear that.
i really want as many people as possible to use my software.
but i wanna freely write codes which i wanna write.
and im tired to support ie.
i hope 25% of people(who use chrome and will use ff4 soon) are many enough.

Comment: @js_: Good luck with it. I'd say that extending `Object.prototype` is a **really** big hammer, though. Couldn't you create a base object type of your own and add the properties to *its* prototype?

Comment: thanks for your advice. 
i think its difficult because i plan to add a few functions to operate Object object, for example, a object-cloning function, a iterating function like jQuery.each, a function to count object's properties, etc.

Comment: @js_: The classic way to handle that in a compatible way is to put them on `Object`, rather than `Object.prototype`. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no such guarantees from jQuery that I am aware of.

jQuery itself doesn't extend any native prototypes, so it is pretty much self contained besides some limited tampering of DOM nodes. However, you can't rely on jQuery plugins written by others to also behave nicely when you extend `Array` and `Object` like this. A lot of other libraries do actually extend `Array`, but extending an `Object` has more severe consequences since it affects every single object.

Will it work with all future versions of jQuery? Take a guess :)

Answer (score 0):

John Resig (creator of jQuery) once wrote that jQuery is safe against extending Array.prototype but not 100% safe against extending Object.prototype (I don't remember the exact place, it was probably in the announcement of a new jQuery version). There is no formal guarantee AFAIK, but it is an aim of jQuery to be resistant to such changes and problems extended prototypes (such as [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6355) or [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6355)) are handled as bugs, though as you can see from the examples, it can take a while to fix them, so even by extending Array you increase the risk of hitting a bug somewhat.